# Etale after base change

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

If a morphism of schemes $f: X\rightarrow Y$ is etale after base change via an etale cover $Z\rightarrow Y$, is $f$ etale?

Comment: Yes. This follows from flat and unramified base change, which are both pretty simple.

Comment: Hi, could you point me to a reference for the theorems you are citing?

Comment: By locality of the condition of being etale, we can reduce to affine neighborhoods. Then it follows from [this](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00U2)

Comment: Which of the many properties are you using?

Comment: I'm worried that people are going to read this too quickly and assume you mean to ask about whether being étale is preserved under base change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $Z\rightarrow Y$ is etale and surjective, then your desired result follows from the fact that being etale is etale-local on the base. More generally, a morphism $f : X\rightarrow Y$ is etale if and only if there exists an fpqc morphism $Z\rightarrow Y$ such that the pullback of $f$ by $Z\rightarrow Y$ is etale.

Here, fpqc means faithfully flat and quasi-compact. In particular, fppf morphisms (faithfully flat and locally of finite presentation) are fpqc, and surjective etale morphisms are fppf.

In short, the property of a morphism being "etale" is fpqc-local on the base, hence *a fortiori* fppf-local on the base, and hence *a fortiori* etale-local on the base.

In fact, a whole slew of properties of morphisms are fpqc, fppf, or etale local on the base.

The chapter on descent:

http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0238

gives a long list of examples of such properties.

Comment: Surjective etale morphisms are not necessarily fppf. However, surjective etale morphisms which are of finite presentation are fppf.

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar So it seems that according to http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/021L , the "pf" in fppf stands for "locally of finite presentation", which makes sense to me, since if you have a family of fppf morphisms which are jointly surjective and hence form an fppf covering, then you'd want the map from the disjoint union of the family to also be an fppf covering. If your family is the family of all inclusions of all affine opens, then each inclusion is of finite presentation, but the induced map from the disjoint union is not quasi-compact, hence only locally of finite presentation.

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar does that make sense? Are there other sources where fppf actually means "flat of finite presentation"?

Comment: you're right. I was misremembering.